# File Not Found when reading a file created during runtime as resource

Tags: java

This line returns `null` because it can't find the file:

`inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);`

The `file` is `src/test/resources/test.tmp`.

The `file` is written to like this:

`Files.write(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()), "test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

If I create `file` before running the application then it works but if I create `file` during runtime (like in a unit test) then `inputStream` returns as `null` because `file` is not found.

How do I create a file during runtime that can be read from the resources directory as a `Stream`?

Comment: Do you *close* the file after creation and before trying to use InputStream with it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I added the code that writes to `file`

Comment: What is your build environment? How are you running your (I assume) test? Normally the resources are copied to the build/target directory where your class files are. The src directory is usually not part of your classpath.

Comment: @HopeyOne: I'm using maven. I append `src/test/resources` to the filename in the unit test so that it creates the temp file in `test/resources` instead of `main/resources`

Comment: @ThreaT , I think the default for maven is that your resources would be copied to the target/test-classes directory which is why you will find it when you create the file beforehand. Where are you writing your on-the-fly test file?

Comment: The `src` directory isn't there at runtime, and resources are (a) not in a file system and (b) read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getResourceAsStream` system *fundamentally* doesn't "do" writes. That method will retrieve a resource from wherever the system is loaded classes from, and there is no guarantee that 'whereever' that might be supports the notion of writing. In fact, *all* available places it could be coming from do not support it.. *except* running from 'raw' class files. Which is a situation that generally only holds during development, thus, making this a pointless exercise.

Hence, the code you wrote does not work and cannot be made to work. If you want to write data, `getResourceAsStream` cannot be involved in the process.

More generally, code is in locations that you can't write to. Or, should be - a few backwater OSes have crazy bad security defaults and allow you to do so. This simply means said OS sucks, not that you should run right off the cliff after them. Hence, any hackery (which is certainly available, but fragile, as it requires certain classpath setups that java doesn't guarantee) should be avoided - all you'll end up obtaining is a directory that you can't write to. Or shouldn't be writing to.

The correct place to store data is.. not 'next to / inside the jar'. It's in the user's home dir, the 'Documents' dir, or some location configured by the user.

You can get to a user's home dir with `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"))`.

### ADDENDUM: Testing with `getResourceAsStream`.

If you want to modify what a certain gRAS call returns for testing purposes, you have a few broad options.

#### Best option: test resources

gRAS can read from anywhere on the classpath, and during test runs, your test stuff *is in there*<sup>1</sup>. Hence, all you really need is to parameterize the string you pass to gRAS, so that test runs can use a different string there. Then, store the test data there. If you need to generate that stuff on the fly, have a separate tiny little app in your test source code that makes it, and then just stick it in the usual `src/test/resources` (And check it in). Randomness in tests is annoying, don't add it if there's no good reason for it.

#### Alternative 1: mock it

I'm not as familiar with these technologies, but some seem to really like it: You can mock out various parts of the system with mocking libraries, thus, you can mock out what `gRAS` returns and return custom InputStreams, e.g. created with:

```java
String testData = "Here is my test data I just generated";
return new ByteArrayInputStream(testData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

#### Alternative 2: Classloader

You can write your own ClassLoader and respond however you please when the system asks you for a resource. This is the *point* of them: If you want to write a java app where classes aren't loaded from a jar file but instead pulled over a network, you can do that, by writing your own ClassLoader. You can even generate the class files on the fly, or take existing ones and modify them with bytecode introspection libraries such as ASM or BCEL, etc. You could write your own and have a system whereby the test code can tell this custom classloader of yours: If anybody asks for "/com/foo/data.txt", just return this data instead of the actual contents of that resource.

It's a little bit involved - start by reading the javadoc of ClassLoader and search the web for a few examples and tutorials, there should be plenty around. This feels like a bit of a heavyhanded solution for the problem, though. However, it most accurately answers the question: "I want to generate what getResourceAsStream returns from my own code, on the fly".

[1] Usually. gRAS calls boil down to 'the classloader' and there are fancypants test setups that stick the test stuff in a separate classloader from the main app stuff - and in that case `gRAS` would no longer be able to find it. The primary aim of such an exercise is to ensure that no application code actually uses anything in the test code, as the point is that the test code isn't there at all during production (but how do you test that - with modular classloaders). However, TestNG and JUnit both, as far as I know, don't do this out of the box. So you should be fine.

Comment: If that's the case then how do you unit test a method that prints the content of a resource as a stream? You would need to have some permanent test files stored there?

Comment: Ah, that is the purpose. You don't want to write data, so much as 'mock up' the response. I'll edit the answer.